# Weight paint doesn't work in weight paint mode

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I can't get the weight paint to work?

[image]
http://prntscr.com/mpmq13

i am in weight paint,i have the bone selected, and it doesnt let me paint. am i doing something wrong with the vertex groups?

Comment: Does this happen for all the brushes? Does the add brush work?

Comment: could you please share your file, or at least the part you're trying to paint? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue. I realized I was trying to paint onto a mirrored section without having actually "applied" the mirror modifier. I am very new at Blender, but thought I'd share in case anyone else falls in the same hole.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the image you posted, at the top left corner, on the tools panel, you have weight set at zero.  It has to be above zero to be able to weight paint.

Comment: If you just happened to have it at that setting when you took the screenshot, then never mind; I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bone wont be connected to the mesh that you are attempting to paint - that's why. otherwise it would work, or perhaps it isn't connected in the correct fashion.

if it moves: it's connected.
( it probably is )

attempt the same thing on other meshes, delete the bone - re-add it. try things that would usually fix a computer:

Turn it on + off ( delete it and re-add it )
Try on other meshes.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters your weight is set to zero. That is the amount of influence you want your mesh to have. So it would bring down the values to zero. However, if you want to lower the value then you are on the right on.

However I think your main issue is that you don't have the correct object in weight paint mode. It seems the ears are in weight paint mode but ont the rest of the mesh. Make sure to either make them part of the same object by sellecting both and hitting "CTRL+J" or, parent the body to the armature by sellecting the mesh THEN the armature an hitting "Shift+P."